# Toast message is not working in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toast

This method is binding the data on the list:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindItems(userList[position])
    holder.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Delete Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    })
    holder.imgCopy.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Copy Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    })
}
```

Error getting  :

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments
>   supplied:  public open fun makeText(p0: Context!, p1: CharSequence!,
>   p2: Int): Toast! defined in android.widget.Toast

please check and help

Answer (score 2):

use

```
Toast.makeText(<Your Activity Context>,"Copy Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

instead of

```
Toast.makeText(this,"Copy Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

How do you get context

```
Context context;
```

1-

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
   super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
   context = recyclerView.getContext();
}
```

2-

```
@Override
public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
   context = parent.getContext();

   return YourViewHolder;
}
```

3-

```
holder.itemView.getContext()
```

4-

```
holder.imgDelete.getContext()
```

5-

Pass activity context in constructor for CustomAdapter

Comment: tried :  Toast .makeText(CustomAdapter,"Delete Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()       //but not working

Comment: use your activity context not adapter.

Comment: please let me know how to add activity in adapter class. As my function  onBindViewHolder is in customAdapter class.

Comment: try this => holder.itemView.getContext()

Comment: @Rahul Could you just mark the answer as an accepted answer so nobody get confused ..just like i was.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the Application context, used here should be the activity class context, instead of `this`, because `this` inside an onClickListener, is actually not a applicationContext to the activity but that to the parent view.

Try this:

```
Toast.makeText(<Here_comes_your_activity_context>,"Copy Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Dont forget to replace your activity context here, with your own.

Comment: tried : Toast .makeText(CustomAdapter,"Delete Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //but not working

Answer (score 1):

You don't have context in on click listener by just passing this. Get context from view instead.

Replace `this` to `holder.imgDelete.context`

```
 holder.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(holder.imgDelete.context,"Delete Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a whole different approach.(BTW - I know you work in Kotlin, I'll share my code in java which I'm sure you'll understand but it will assist java coders as well).

Try saving a Context as a variable in your activity (in the on create set that variable to "this" of the activity.
Make that variable a static variable.
Like this:

```
public class MainActivity extands Activity{

    private static Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
       //your code...
       context = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
       return context;
    }
}
```

Then inside the Toast just do this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindItems(userList[position])
    holder.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getContext(),"Delete Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    })
    holder.imgCopy.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getContext(),"Copy Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    })
}
```