# problem, can't create an event that generates a toast message on kotlin recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm using Kotlin to create an event that generates a toast message on click of a recyclerview. I run into trouble making  a Tost message in a recyclerview event.
I tried the following page, but couldn't solve it.
[Toast message is not working in Recycler View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61857900/toast-message-is-not-working-in-recycler-view)

**error code is**

```
in kotlin & None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: public open fun makeText(p0: Context!, p1: CharSequence!, p2: Int): Toast! defined in android.widget.Toast public open fun makeText(p0: Context!, p1: Int, p2: Int): Toast! defined in android.widget.Toast
```

**PrintActivity.kt**

```
package com.questionbank

class PrintActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val vBinding = ActivityPrintBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(vBinding.root)
        val helper = SqliteHelper(this, "myDB.sql", 1)

        var recyclerViewAdapter = CustomAdapter()
        recyclerViewAdapter.listData = helper.select()
        vBinding.myRecyclerView.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter
        vBinding.myRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        vBinding.myRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)

        )

    }

    class CustomAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.Holder>() {
        var listData = ArrayList<questionType>()

        inner class Holder(val vBinding: QuestionLayoutRecyclerBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vBinding.root) {
            fun setData(id:Int?, question: String, answer: String, exp: String) {
                vBinding.printId.text=id.toString()

                
                vBinding.myLinear.setOnClickListener {
                    // error occur
                    Toast.makeText(this@PrintActivity, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
            val vBinding = QuestionLayoutRecyclerBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
            return Holder(vBinding)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
            val question = listData[position]
            holder.setData(question.id, question.question, question.answer, question.exp)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return listData.size
        }

    }

}
```

**activity_print**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PrintActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**question_layout_recycler.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/printId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to fix,

1. Make CustomAdapter class as inner class.

   ```
   innner class CustomAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.Holder>() {
   ```

So toast function it will take constant from activity class.

2. In viewholder, get context from view. it.context will get context from linearlayout.

   ```
   vBinding.myLinear.setOnClickListener {
                    Toast.makeText(it.context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
   ```

Its recommended to place adapter logic in separate file and use second solution.
So you dont need to make adapter as inner class.

Comment: so helpful help thanks

Comment: Please do upvote if you are okay. Happy coding!!